# Django API issue trying to create a method to add lookup data from another table

Tags: django, api, rest

Django API Issue

I am wanting to append a data field [site_name] stored in the parent table [USERaffiliates]  to a child record [USERaffylinks].

site_name method: I am doing this so that I have access to the site_name field on a Vue.js component ... where I display the link data -- –

There is a 1:Many relationship with 1 USERaffiliates having many USERaffylinks.

I would so love some help - I have tried so many things but keep getting errors in the API when I try adding a new USERaffylinks record via the API browser screen.

I tried adding this method > def site_name - but failed.

Here's the traceback
[traceback image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xopv7.jpg)

Without the site_name method, the API works just fine.

def site_name(self): is wrong somehow.

```
class USERaffylinks(models.Model):
    owner_link_useraffyid = models.ForeignKey(USERaffiliates, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    owner_link_short = models.CharField(max_length=27, null=True, default=None, blank=True) 

    def site_name(self):
        if USERaffiliates.objects.filter(id=self.owner_link_useraffyid).exists():
            sitename = USERaffiliates.objects.get(id=self.owner_link_useraffyid)
            return sitename.site_name
        else:
            return "ERROR"
```

**FULL MODELS { without the def site_name(self) }  -- API works fine with just this**

```
class USERaffiliates(models.Model):
    owneruserid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1) 
    user_category = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, default=None, blank=True ) 
    registered_email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    site_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
 ... ... ....

class USERaffylinks(models.Model):
    owner_link_useraffyid = models.ForeignKey(USERaffiliates, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
owner_link_short = models.CharField(max_length=27, null=True, default=None, blank=True)

... ... ...
```

**USERaffylinks View**

```
@action(methods=['POST'], detail=True)
class AffyPartnerLinksViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset= USERaffylinks.objects.all()  #need to filter on login user > owneruserid=request.user.id
    serializer_class = USERaffylinksSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)                #later  IsAuthentiated
```

**Serialiser File**

```
class USERaffiliatesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = USERaffiliates
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_fields = ['user_category_desc','user_status_desc','num_affy_links']
        extra_kwargs = {'owneruserid': {'required':True}}

    def get_field_names(self, declared_fields, info):
        expanded_fields = super(USERaffiliatesSerializer, self).get_field_names(declared_fields, info)

        if getattr(self.Meta, 'extra_fields', None):
            return expanded_fields + self.Meta.extra_fields
        else:
            return expanded_fields

class USERaffylinksSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = USERaffylinks
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_fields = ['site_name']
        extra_kwargs = {'owner_link_useraffyid': {'required':True}}

    def get_field_names(self, declared_fields, info):
        expanded_fields = super(USERaffylinksSerializer, self).get_field_names(declared_fields, info)

        if getattr(self.Meta, 'extra_fields', None):
            return expanded_fields + self.Meta.extra_fields
        else:
            return expanded_fields
```

Comment: can you share your `views.py` file for `USERaffylinks` + your traceback so that other developers can understand which exact file/line creating the problem?

Comment: And what you are supposing to accomplish with the `site_name` method?

Comment: Thank you -

site_name method: I am doing this so that I have access to the site_name field on a Vue.js component ... where I display the link data --

Comment: View added and traceback added thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing this error due to the wrong use of the `actions` decorator. As [rest_framework's viewsets docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) suggest that you can use `actions` decorator for making some extra actions for routing. In your case you are trying `actions` decorator on class which mean, you are making your whole class **a routable** which only accept **POST** method.
so instead of using this:

```py
@action(methods=['POST'], detail=True)
class AffyPartnerLinksViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset= USERaffylinks.objects.all()  #need to filter on login user > owneruserid=request.user.id
    serializer_class = USERaffylinksSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)                #later  IsAuthentiated
```

try this:

```py
class AffyPartnerLinksViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset= USERaffylinks.objects.all()  #need to filter on login user > owneruserid=request.user.id
    serializer_class = USERaffylinksSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)                #later  IsAuthentiated
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: I tried  enclosing in ( ) as well but no luck either

Comment: I have changed my question a little -- the issue is with the def site_name(self): method -- but I do not know what (I corrected the previous issue in the serialiser with missing brackets - which was a 2nd problem - but the primary problem still o/s )

Comment: Now I totally changed my answer, hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

`USERaffylinks.owner_link_useraffyid` is a ForeignKey so when accessed it will perform a DB query to access the related object. You need to fix the way you check to see if the `ForeignKey` contains a valid id, simply access the field and catch any `DoesNotExist` errors

```
class USERaffylinks(models.Model):
    owner_link_useraffyid = models.ForeignKey(USERaffiliates, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    owner_link_short = models.CharField(max_length=27, null=True, default=None, blank=True) 

    def site_name(self):
        try:
            return self.owner_link_useraffyid.site_name
        except USERaffiliates.DoesNotExist:
            return "ERROR"
```

If the `ForeignKey` can be null (or at least invalid) then maybe it would make sense to make the field nullable instead of having a default value

Comment: Thank you Iain - you hit it in one

def site_name(self):
        return self.owner_link_useraffyid.site_name

Was the final solution SO SIMPLE ! Boy is there SO much to learn -- thanks for helping deeply appreciate it :) Yahooo